# vim + c++: insert a uuid in a guard clause

Tags: c++, vim, autocmd, guard-clause

I'm trying to automate file comment headers. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to insert the result of the `uuidgen` command into my header using vim's autocmd.

Inside the header, the placeholder text is present, like this:

```
#ifndef _UUID_
#define _UUID_

// Code goes here!

#endif // _UUID_
```

The autocmd line to populate `_UUID_` in .vimrc is:

```
autocmd bufnewfile *.h exe "1,$s/_UUID_/" . r!uuidgen ."/g"
```

The problem is coming in under r!uuidgen.  **How do i insert the result of a shell-command-execution as text in the autocmd line?  Or in a vi substitution command for that matter?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use system(), and don't forget to chomp the result
-> `matchstr(system('uuidgen'), "[^\n\r]*")`

NB: For more complex templates, you could use solutions like [mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate). For instance, in [c-header.template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/mu-template/trunk/after/template/c/internals/c-header.template), you'd have had to change the value of `s:guard` to the call to matchtr()+system().

Comment: Worked, many thanks!  Will have to checkout your templates sometime.

Answer (score 1):

My resulting autocmd line after Luc's suggestion was, for posterity sake:

```
autocmd bufnewfile *.h exe "1,$g/_UUID_/s/_UUID_/" . matchstr(system('uuidgen'), "[^\n\r]*")
```

Comment: A simple "%s/_UUID_" should be enough. However, I'm not sure about the order in which several autocommands are executed. That's one of the reasons I always prefer to rely on functions (or ftplugins, or local vimrcs) where autocommands are concerned.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte - My vim-fu is improving.  Thanks for the tips.